# published date in newsflash module

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm using newsflash module on my Joomla site and would like to have a published date shown at every article but there is no possibility to activate this in module settings. Any suggestions?

If I click read more, there I can activate date under article settings.

Thanks

UPDATE: There is also no module folder "mod_articles_newsflash" which should be there according to Joomlas help https://docs.joomla.org/Help33:Extensions_Module_Manager_Articles_Newsflash

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)).

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've somehow solved it but it is not a solution that I would recommend.